# Convert indian standard time to mysql datetime format using php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, datetime

I have my indian standard time like ,

**Wed Oct 08 2014 07:40:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)** , which is created by javascript,

Now i want to change this format to 2014-11-10 07:40:00 to store in mysql.

how can i do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you

```
$date = "Wed Oct 08 2014 07:40:00";
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($date));
```

output

> 2014-10-08 07:40:00

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library.

```
var a = "Wed Oct 08 2014 07:40:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)";
var b = moment(a).zone(0).format(YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss);
```

Comment: using php how can i do

Comment: check marcel's answer

Answer (score 0):

I personally would transform your time with the `time()`-function to the unix format amd with then with `date()` back to your liking:

http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php

i.g.: `date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time())` would give you the momentary time in the desired format.

edit: I forget the damn '...', but I corrected that. The accepted answer ist correct and a little bit better than mine.